# Is it possible to add a javascript chart in a webview in Xamari.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, chart.js

Hy guys,

I would like to know if is possible to create a line chart like this [Linear chart with Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/multi-axis.html) with javascript in a WebView in a Xamarin.Forms page, the values of the lines must be added in code.

I followed this tutorial, to implement a [Hybrid WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview)

The tutorial is working fine more or less, but I changed the index.htm file and I added the utils.js to have the same chart as in the first link.

[image: Content directory]

The content of index and utils.js is the same as you cand find in the first link with F12.

[image: Line Chart content]

But I don't know what I need more, my intuition says that the utils.js file is not working fine. This is the result when I run the app, I hope someone has a solution :)

[image: Result]

Now I can see the chart fine in the Xamarin.Forms page, to do it I just copied all the files and changed the route in multi-axi.html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Line Chart Multiple Axes</title>
    <script src="../../../../dist/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../utils.js"></script>
    <style>
    canvas {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:75%;">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <button id="randomizeData">Randomize Data</button>
    <script>
        var lineChartData = {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                fill: false,
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ],
                yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
            }, {
                label: 'My Second dataset',
                borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                fill: false,
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ],
                yAxisID: 'y-axis-2'
            }]
        };

        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            window.myLine = Chart.Line(ctx, {
                data: lineChartData,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    hoverMode: 'index',
                    stacked: false,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Multi Axis'
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                            display: true,
                            position: 'left',
                            id: 'y-axis-1',
                        }, {
                            type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                            display: true,
                            position: 'right',
                            id: 'y-axis-2',

                            // grid line settings
                            gridLines: {
                                drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
                            },
                        }],
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
            lineChartData.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
                    return randomScalingFactor();
                });
            });

            window.myLine.update();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The result:

[image: Line chart with Javascript]

I have one last problem, the `lineChartData` variable must be created in the .cs file with custom data, how I do that?

Comment: When I used your provide link to `webview` directly, I can not see this chart.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/multi-axis.html

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT any idea how to create the chart from c# side?

Comment: I recommend you to use `oxyplot` to achieve it, https://www.oxyplot.org/

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT yeah, I implement it with OxyPlot, but doesn't have a great UX and doesn't have the functionablity to show the value of a point when you tap it

Comment: Yes, Oxyplot cannot achieve that easily, If you want to achieve that, you should adjust the html layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a ton of people having this issues online of using js charts in Xamarin.Forms so I took some inspiration from HybridWeb view and some Gists online and created a Nuget Package to solve this.

https://github.com/ChristopherMWood/XamarinChartJSPlugin

It will allow you to configure charts in C# and it converts them to chart.js charts in a WebView. As of writing this it's fairly new but it helps solve the main line use cases using CHart.js.